# Have a scrollable menu, but remove scrolling from body on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iphone

If on a small screen, my website changes it's menu to a hamburger menu button which, if clicked, toggles a sidebar, containing a stacked version of the menu. This sidebar is on top of the normal website (`position: fixed; z-index: 5;`). When the sidebar is toggled, a body-overlay is toggled too. This prevents you from clicking any links on the actual site.

What I'm trying to do is removing the scroll capability for the body of the website, but still allow scrolling in that menu-sidebar because on an iPhone 4 for example it's too big to fit the screen.

I tried to get this behavior with setting `overflow-y: hidden;` on the body, if the sidebar is active (showing). Furthermore I gave the sidebar an `overflow-y: scroll;`. This actually works, but only on a computer (if the screen is resized to the width of a mobile device).

Unfortunately on my iPhone this has no effect. If I scroll, I'm actually scrolling the body and not the sidebar...

So how do I disable the scrolling function on a mobile phone?

I know that it's possible to do the following in JavaScript, but that will not let you scroll in the menu-sidebar...

```
document.ontouchstart = function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

---

[image]

---

## Solved

#### HTML Structure

```
<body>
  <div class="mobile-nav closed">
    <!-- Menu -->
  </div>
  <div class="body-overlay"></div>
  
  <!-- Page Content -->
</body>
```

#### jQuery Code

```
$( '.hamburger' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
  $( this ).toggleClass( 'is-active' );
  $( '.mobile-nav' ).toggleClass( 'closed' );
  $( '.body-overlay' ).fadeToggle( 300 );
  $( 'body' ).toggleClass( 'no-scroll' ).promise().done( function(){
    var touchScroll = function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    };

    if ( $(this).hasClass( 'no-scroll' ) ) {
      $( '.body-overlay' ).bind( 'touchmove', touchScroll );
      $( '.mobile-nav' ).unbind( 'touchmove', touchScroll );
    }
    else {
      $( '.body-overlay' ).unbind( 'touchmove', touchScroll );
    }
  } );

  e.preventDefault();
} );
```

This code works well. `$('.hamburger')` is the hamburger menu button. It's class `.is-active` changes it to a cross. The second ant the third statement should be clear. The fourth statement ist the interesting one. On the body I'm toggling the `.no-scroll` class which sets an `overflow-y: hidden` to the body and an `overflow-y: scroll` to the menu. As said, this has no effect on mobile devices, so as a callback, I'm firing another function. In that function I'm first storing a function inside a variable, then I'm checking if the body has the `.no-scroll` class (menu is open) or if it hasn't (menu closed). If the menu is opened, I'm preventing scrolling on the `.body-overlay` (`body` did **not** work) but enabling scrolling on the nav. If the menu is being closed, the prevent must be unbind, otherwise scrolling will still be disabled!

Hopefully that helps! :)

Comment: document.ontouchstart... effects the whole page, but with jquery you could try something like `$('body').on({ touchstart: function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }  })` ?  or even perhaps try replacing `touchstart` with `touchmove` if you wish to enable clicks. Alternatively you can change `$('body').on...` to focus on your 'body-overlay' div and add e.stopPropogation(); after preventDefault() . curious to see if either of these work.

Comment: Hey @Sam0, I just updated my question. If you're interested, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well done, effective script. A few notes:

- best practice is to use `.on` and `.off` instead of `.bind` as these
  have been deprecated and may cause problems should you need to update your jQuery library later.
- your `touchScroll` function doesn't need to be within these jQuery
  function calls as currently it can't be accessed by another function
  if for whatever reason you wish to call it again elsewhere.
- lastly, you never appear to unbind `touchScroll` from your
  `.body-overlay` div? if this isn't necessary (to unbind) then best to
  declare it outside of your if statement and maybe before this whole
  js block to avoid calling it repeatedly.